# How to upgrade PWA to latest version?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, pwa-studio

How to upgrade PWA to latest version?

I want to upgrade all PWA packages to latest version so is there any particular steps ?

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use This Link

**https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/guides/upgrading-versions/**

And follow the steps to upgrade all PWA packages to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading **`PWA (Progressive Web App)`** to the latest version in Magento 2 can be done by following these steps:

1. Backup your Magento 2 website: Before starting the upgrade process,
   it's important to make a backup of your website in case anything
   goes wrong during the upgrade process.
2. Update Magento 2: Make sure that your Magento 2 installation is up
   to date by running the command **`composer update`** from the root
   directory of your Magento 2 installation.
3. Update the PWA Studio: Run the command **`yarn upgrade @magento/pwa`**
   from the root directory of your PWA Studio installation. This will
   upgrade the PWA Studio to the latest version.
4. Rebuild the PWA Studio: Run the command **`yarn run build`** from the root
   directory of your PWA Studio installation. This will rebuild the PWA
   Studio with the latest version.
5. Deploy the PWA Studio: Run the command **`yarn run deploy`** from the root
   directory of your PWA Studio installation. This will deploy the
   newly built PWA Studio to your Magento 2 installation.
6. Test the PWA Studio: After the upgrade, it's important to test the
   PWA Studio to make sure everything is working as expected.

**`Note:`** Make sure to follow the right version of PWA studio as per your Magento version.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**